# I am unable to get the JDBC connection for the below configuration. Getting the error: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

Tags: hibernate-mapping

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connectin.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection_username">root</property>
        <property name="connection_password">root</property>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Programm:  In which I am just tyring to print the session print the session g=factory object to check if the connection is established.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    // Here i am just trying to print the SessionFactory object to check if the connection is 
     //established.
        Configuration c= new Configuration();
        c.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory s= c.buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception when I run the code. I am using JDK-11, Hibernate 5.6.1, and MySQL 8

```
Feb 08, 2022 8:40:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
Feb 08, 2022 8:40:28 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Feb 08, 2022 8:40:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
Feb 08, 2022 8:40:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at com.hibernateprogms.App.main(App.java:14)

Feb 08, 2022 8:40:28 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResultSet(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.getTables(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at com.hibernateprogms.App.main(App.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for `UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl`. When this is put into the config as connection provider for Hibernate, then it will ignore the values in `<session-factory>`.